# Dynamic requires in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Edit: I created wrappers for each different component, required the necessary collections and passed them as props to a main, generic component.**

We made 3 very similar components using React, and ended up having three really similar files with some minor modifications, depending on the specific component.
My question is really simple (but might be hard to implement), we want to utilize the same file for that base, so i want to dynamically use requires, and initialize variables, how can i do it?

```
var ProtocolSelectedCollection = require("../collections/ProtocolSelectedCollection");
var selectedCollection = new ProtocolSelectedCollection();
var baseURL = Utils.getSystemUrl();

easyGrid({
    gridName: "protocolSelectedCollection"
});
```

In the code above, for example, i would like to require a different file from **/collections/**, depending on the component, and i would also like to name the **gridName** differently.
So, how can i do it? I will post more code if necessary or clear any doubts about it.
So here is the full component, it's really small.

```
var React = require('react');

const Utils = require("Utils");

var RowCt = require("reactor/src/FlexGrid/components/Layout/Row/Row");
var Col = require("reactor/src/FlexGrid/components/Layout/Col.jsx");
var Row = require("reactor/src/FlexGrid/components/Layout/Row/RowPresentation.jsx");
var Box = require("reactor/src/FlexGrid/components/Layout/Box.jsx");
var ContentLabel = require("reactor/src/Atomic/components/Mols/ContentLabel.jsx");
var AsyncLoading = require("reactor/src/Atomic/components/Helpers/AsyncLoading/AsyncLoading");
var Store = require("reactor/src/store/store");
var Provider = require("react-redux").Provider;
var FormControl = require('reactor/src/Form/components/Atoms/FormControl/FormControl');
var FormGroup = require("reactor/src/Form/components/Mols/FormGroup");
var InputAddon = require("reactor/src/Form/components/Atoms/InputAddon");
var InputGroup = require("reactor/src/Form/components/Mols/InputGroup/InputGroup.jsx");
var easyGrid = require("reactor/src/FlexGrid/components/Helpers/EasyGrid");
var when = require("when");

var ProtocolSelectedCollection = require("../collections/ProtocolSelectedCollection");
var selectedCollection = new ProtocolSelectedCollection();
var baseURL = Utils.getSystemUrl();

easyGrid({
    gridName: "protocolSelectedCollection"
});

var cursorPointer = {
    cursor: 'pointer'
};

var rowWrapper = {
    borderWidth: '0px 0px 1px',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderColor: 'rgb(204, 204, 204)',
    marginBottom: '10px',
    cursor: 'pointer'
};


require("./ProtocolAuthorizedWidget.css");
require("reactorCmps/tokens/general");

module.exports = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount() {
        var me = this;

        return me.loadData();
    },

    filterValue: "",

    loadData() {
        var me = this;

        return me.refs.async.getWrappedInstance().loadData(true);
    },

    getChildren(data) {
        var me = this, protocolsData = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [], protocols = [];

        if (!protocolsData.length) {
            return (
                <span>{SE.t(103092)}</span>
            );
        }

        protocolsData.map(function(element, i) {
            protocols.push(
                <div style={rowWrapper}
                    key={i}
                    onMouseLeave={me.setRowState.bind(me, element.cdproctype, 'leave')}
                    onMouseOver={me.setRowState.bind(me, element.cdproctype, 'over')}
                    onClick={me.startProtocol.bind(me, element.cdproctype)}
                    title={SE.t(104859)}>

                    <RowCt
                        oid={element.cdproctype}
                        selectType={0}
                        multireducerKey={"protocolSelectedCollection"}>

                        <Col xs sm md lg>
                            <Row nested>
                                <Col xs={1} sm={1} md={1} lg={1} >
                                    <div ref={"protocol" + element.cdproctype}></div>
                                    <img ref={"protocolImage" + element.cdproctype} 
                                        src={baseURL + "/common/images/type_icons/64x64/" + element.fgicon + ".png"} 
                                        className="rowImage" />
                                </Col>
                                <Col xs={11} sm={11} md={11} lg={11}>
                                    <Box>
                                        <ContentLabel title={element.idproctype} text={element.nmtitle}></ContentLabel>
                                    </Box>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Col>
                    </RowCt>
                </div>

            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {protocols}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },

    startProtocol(cdproctype) {
        var url = baseURL + "/document/dc_protocol/protocol_data.php?caption=&action=1&cdproctype=" + cdproctype;
        var width = 700;
        var height = 515;

        Utils.openPopUp(url, width, height); 
    },

    setRowState(cdproctype, event) {
        var me = this;

        if (event === 'over') {
            $(me.refs.async.getWrappedInstance().refs['protocolImage' + cdproctype]).hide();
            $(me.refs.async.getWrappedInstance().refs['protocol' + cdproctype]).addClass("se-valign btn btn-success seicon-play playButton rowImage");
        } else if (event === 'leave') {
            $(me.refs.async.getWrappedInstance().refs['protocolImage' + cdproctype]).show();
            $(me.refs.async.getWrappedInstance().refs['protocol' + cdproctype]).removeClass();
        } 
    },

    filterProtocol(e) {
        var me = this;
        var enterKeyCode = 13;

        if (e.target) {
            me.filterValue = e.target.value;
        }

        if (e.nativeEvent.keyCode === enterKeyCode) {
            me.loadData();
        }
    },

    getData() {
        var me = this, deferred = when.defer();
        var oid = me.props.CardOid;
        var searchTerm = me.filterValue;

        selectedCollection.fetch({oid: oid, searchTerm: searchTerm}).then(function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    },

    render() {
        var me = this, searchFilter;

        searchFilter = (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <InputGroup>
                            <InputAddon 
                                onClick={me.loadData}
                                style={cursorPointer}
                                className="seicon-search"
                                title={SE.t(214653)}
                                >

                            </InputAddon>
                            <div>
                                <FormControl
                                    onKeyPress={me.filterProtocol}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </InputGroup>
                    </FormGroup>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {searchFilter}
                </div>

                <Provider store={Store} withRef>
                    <AsyncLoading
                        ref="async"
                        oid={"protocolSelectedCollection" + me.props.CardOid}
                        fireLoad
                        loadFn={me.getData}
                        getChildren={me.getChildren}
                    />
                </Provider>

            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

Comment: I don't know your those similar components but, what about using `one component` but render different results based on `props` ? This can save a lot.

Comment: I thought about it..
Can i require a prop?

Comment: Just combine 3 components into one, and pass them props based on your results. I can explain better if you share your codebase.

Comment: Updated with one of the components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your components are really similar,you can create `one single component` which does some actions and renders some result based on props.

Just pass some props. And inside of your component, do your actions like you do in those 3 component separately. Here, i tried to demonstrate how to use props to render different results from same component:

```
class MixedComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props)
    this.state = {type: ''}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.prop1) // if prop1 exists
      this.setState({type: 'do something'})
    else 
      this.setState({type: 'Something else'})
  }

  render() {
    let result;
    if (this.props.prop1) {
      result = (
        <div>
          Render this component based on <strong>{this.props.prop1}</strong>
          <p>Type -> {this.state.type}</p>
        </div>
      )
    } else if (this.props.prop2) {
      result = (
        <div>
          Render this component based on <strong>{this.props.prop2}</strong>
          <p>Type -> {this.state.type}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    else if (this.props.prop3) {
      result = (
        <div>
          Render this component based on <strong>{this.props.prop3}</strong>
          <p>Type -> {this.state.type}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

And use this component with different props in your main component:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Render different results based on props with same component!</h4>
        <hr/>
        <MixedComponent prop1="Hello,"/>
        <MixedComponent prop2="Dear"/>
        <MixedComponent prop3="World!"/>
      </div>
     )
  }
}
```

This is just a demonstration of using props. You can derive the idea from here. Here is a working example on `codepen`:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dREqZK?editors=1010

You can play with it.

Comment: Thanks, the solution was obtained using something similar to what you proposed, the gist of it can be seen here (I use the same name for the prop, just change the value passed).  
https://codepen.io/eliamelfior/pen/OjVyYy

Comment: @EliaMelfior glad to help you